# How can I pass a variable through a quoted expression into a function that returns a function using that value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, tidyeval, non-standard-evaluation

Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) # for percent() function

custom_percent <- function(n){
    function(x){
         return(paste(percent(x), sprintf('(%d)', round(x* (n)))))
    }
 }

mydata = data.frame(x = rep(c('a','b','c'), each=100))

ggplot(mydata) + geom_text(aes_(x=~x, y=~..prop.., 
                           label=bquote(.(custom_percent)(length(x))(..prop..)),
                           stat='count')
```

The function works properly outside of such an environment, but in order to use it with `ggplot`, it has to be quoted in one way or another.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to properly return a generated function that contains a variable that is passed in such a manner. I've tried this:

```
custom_percent <- function(n){
    n = enquo(n)
    function(x){
         return(paste(percent(x), sprintf('(%d)', round(x* (!!n)))))
    }
 }
```

But I get an error when I do this: `Error in !n : invalid argument type`

Does anyone know how to properly use the desired value of `n` in the function returned by `custom_percent()`?

And before anyone asks, I know I can generate the statistics in a summary data frame beforehand *or* use `utils::getAnywhere()` as a workaround, but that's not the point of the question.

Comment: What do you need as your output?

Comment: eg. what should `custom_percent(3)` output?

Comment: What's version of `ggplot2` are you using? I'm using dev version and get `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unknown input:function`

Comment: Note that you can only use `!!` in arguments to tidy eval functions. `paste()`, `sprintf()` and `round()` are all normal functions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't your function - which looks fine as originally written.  You're missing parenthesis in your geom_text call, which I think is the primary issue.

```
custom_percent <- function(n){
  function(x){
    return(paste(percent(x), sprintf('(%d)', round(x* (n)))))
  }
}

# I made the data slightly more variable
mydata = data.frame(x = rep(c('a','b','c'), rbinom(3, 100, .8)))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x)) + 
  # geom_bar(stat = 'count') + 
  geom_text(aes_(label=bquote(.(custom_percent)(length(x))(..count.. / sum(..count..)))),
    stat='count')
```

I think this gets you what you want (and throwing `..prop..` in there works too, it's just flat 1s for this data - which did not make sense to me.  If thats what you wanted/expected, by all means switch it back.  You might check out https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/ - that shows where you can use `..prop..` and `..count..`, but it doesn't really explain why).

Another thing you can do (taking advantage of `..prop..` as written):

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x, y = ..prop..), stat = 'count') + 
  # geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), stat = 'count') +
  geom_text(aes_(label=bquote(.(custom_percent)(length(x))((..count..) / sum(..count..)))),
    stat='count') + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base r `substitute` to capture the whole expression and then write the expression as a `functionBody`

```
custom_percent <- function(n){
 n=eval(n)
 m=substitute(return(paste(percent(x), sprintf('(%d)', round(x*n)))))
 `functionBody<-`(function(x)1,parent.frame(),m)
}

s=3
custom_percent(s)
function (x) 
return(paste(percent(x), sprintf("(%d)", round(x * 3))))
```

as you can see, `n` has been replaced with `3`. You can try any other number. And it will work